# i want to retrieve tagged pics in instagram using graph api. but i got this error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, laravel-8

url = "1321231231312/?fields=tags.limit(100){media_type,media_url,id,timestamp,permalink,username,caption,like_count}"

"error" => "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action"

Answer (score 0):

You need to have these permissions set up on your app:

- `pages_show_list`
- `instagram_basic`
- `instagram_manage_comments`
- `pages_read_engagement`
- `pages_read_user_content`